# Debugging on a mobile device?

Tags: iphone, debugging, mobile, responsive-design

i have a mobile website i am converting from a desktop site but have some unwanted white space that i cannot seem to remove. Its either padding or margin somewhere but i cant track it down.

Is there a way to the same as firefox's inspect and see exactly what styles affect what?

The site is being made via media queries and i cannot find any emulators that work with this.

Thanks.

Using this meta view port should be the correct width for iphones right?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to see your website source?

if you use [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/mobile) you can add `view-source:` before any URL that you want to see it's source.

---

For example:

`http://www.google.com` shows you Google website and `view-source:http://www.google.com` shows you Google website source.

---

**Note:**  maybe it work on other browser but I didn't test it.